# Export a DataTable generated by a function (HTML tables) to Excel

Tags: jquery, data-export, datatable, excel, salesforceexcelconnector

Based on the requirements, i have to generate 3 dataTable using a JQuery function like below and i need to implenet a button to export the result into an excel file.
I'm currently using
`contentType="{!IF(isExport = true, 'application/vnd.ms-excel#UnitSummary.xls', '')` and then i have
`<apex:commandButton style="float: right" action="{!export}" value="Export" />` export() just sets isExport to true. 
The problem is although it generates an excel file, the file is empty. It does not show any data. I'm assuming it's because I'm not using apex tags to generate the tables and use JQuery functions like:

```
function displaySummary(){

var summaryTable = '<div><big><b>Child Summary</b></big></div><br><table id="childTable" class="display" cellspacing="0">';

summaryTable += '<thead><th>Type</th><th>Sub-Type</th><th>Status</th><th>Total Units</th></thead><tbody>';
.
.
.
$("#childTable").DataTable({"searching": false, "lengthChange": false});
```

Can anyone help me to find a way to show the data on the excel file please?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is facing the same issue, I ended up using table2excel plug-in instead of using application/vnd.ms-excel and it solved my issue.